# Select max value from a table and increment it in another

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm struggling with a sql query, and will appreciate any help.

I have two tables, they both have a sort column. The first one looks like this:

| person_id | image_name | sort_number |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 739 | chest.png | 1 |
| 739 | legs.png | 2 |

And the second table like this

| person_id | advert | sort_number |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 739 | house.png | 1 |
| 739 | car.png | 2 |

I want to be able to select the max sort_number from the table1 and make the first sort_number in table2 *(house.png)* to become 3, and the sort_number for *car.png)* to become 4.

Essentially, what I'm looking to achieve is an insert statement that selects  from table2 and insert into table1, but I need the sort_number not to have duplicate, so the starting sort_number from the table2 should be the max of table1+1...and so on. If table1 does not have the person, I simply insert and not change the sort_number value.

I would appreciate of someone can help me please.

Comment: avatar is decade old kylie jenner - good choice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
With grouped as
(Select person_id, max(sort_num) as maxsort
 From table1
 Group by person_id)

Select t2.person_id, t2.advert, t2.sort_num + coalesce(g.maxsort,0) as newsortnum
From table t2
Left join grouped g on t2.person_id = g.person_id
```

This will get max value of sort number for each key in the first table, and then attempt to join the second table to this grouped dataset. If there is a match, you add your second table's value to the max, and retain the value from the second table otherwise.

Comment: Thanks a million....this is exactly what I was looking for. It ran out of the box. You are a star.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `UNION ALL` and `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT
        person_id,
        image_name,
        sort_number,
        1 sort_table
    FROM dbo.Table1 t1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 
        person_id,
        advert,
        sort_number,
        2
    FROM dbo.Table2 t2
)
SELECT 
    person_id,
    image_name,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY person_id ORDER BY sort_table, sort_number) sort_number
FROM CTE
;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
insert into table2(person_id, advert, sort_number)
select table1.person_id, table1.image_name, table1.sort_number + table2.sort_number
from table1
join table2
on 1 = 1
left join table2 newer
on table2.sort_number < newer.sort_number
left join table1 mismatch
on table2.person_id = mistmatch.person_id and table2.advert = mismatch.image_name
where newer.person_id is null and mismatch.person_id is null
```

Firs join: we need to pair table1 and table2

Second join: we make sure that table2 record in the pair is the newest

Third join: we make sure that we do not insert what's already there.